# Buildroot - menuconfig creates config, but won't make

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, buildroot, mips64, linux-toolchain

I'm trying to use buildroot to create a cross-compiler toolchain for MIPS64 (little endian).

I have run `make menuconfig` and have set the target to MIPS64 (little endian). Also I am being told that the config file has been generated and I can run make (as below)

```
configuration written to /home/blah/Downloads/buildroot-2018.02.6/mipsel64.config

*** End of the configuration.
*** Execute 'make' to start the build or try 'make help'.
```

So, I then run `make` and I get the following:

```
Makefile:864: *** Please configure Buildroot first (e.g. "make menuconfig").  Stop.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy your buildroot config file to .config file in your buildroot directory. It may look like:

cp /home/blah/Downloads/buildroot-2018.02.6/mipsel64.config /home/blah/Downloads/buildroot-2018.02.6/.config

assuming that /home/blah/Downloads/buildroot-2018.02.6/ is your buildroot compilation directory.

Then try to do make.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ask `menuconfig` to save to a file, just exit and answer `Yes` when asked `Do you wish to save your new configuration?`. This way it will save a file named `.config`, which is exactly the file neeeded for building.